# How to ignore special characters ($ ^ + () {} etc.) from string, with the help of regex expression by using replaceAll() method

Tags: java, regex

I am using java replaceAll() method to replace part of String with another String and its working great but, the problem comes when my file name contains characters like $ ^ + ( ) { } [ ] etc. In this case pattern matching fails and the original String remains as it is.
Sample code to show case my use case is as follow:

```
String messageBody = "src=\"http://thinconnect.interactcrm.com:36061/FileDownloader/4/outbound/31358/file+name.jpeg\" style=\"height:225px\"";
messageBody =  messageBody.replaceAll("(http|https)://(?:[^\\s]*)/FileDownloader/4/outbound/31358/file+name.jpeg", "cid: 14890411127853");
System.out.println(messageBody);
```

The expected output is:

> src="cid: 14890411127853" style="height:225px"

but it gives:

> src="http://thinconnect.interactcrm.com:36061/FileDownloader/4/outbound/31358/file+name.jpeg" style="height:225px"

How can I get it working by ignoring special characters that we use to form regex expression from my file name.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Raman Yes, its working, the regex part is actually being used to avoid ip:port combo otherwise the exact string should match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have unescaped metacharacters in your URL pattern, including a plus and a literal dot.  Escape them, using the following pattern:

```
(http|https)://(?:[^\\s]*)/FileDownloader/4/outbound/31358/file\\+name\\.jpeg
                                                               ^^^ escape dot and plus sign
```

**Full code:**

```
String messageBody = "src=\"http://thinconnect.interactcrm.com:36061/FileDownloader/4/outbound/31358/file+name.jpeg\" style=\"height:225px\"";
messageBody =  messageBody.replaceAll("(http|https)://(?:[^\\s]*)/FileDownloader/4/outbound/31358/file\\+name\\.jpeg", "cid: 14890411127853");
System.out.println(messageBody);
```

**Output:**

```
src="cid: 14890411127853" style="height:225px"
```

**Update:**

If you don't know in advance what the exact pattern will be, but you know it might have metacharacters, which would require escaping for use in a replacement, then Java provides a method for this: [Pattern.quote()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote(java.lang.String))

To see how it works, we can split your pattern into two parts:

```
String part1 = "(http|https)://(?:[^\\s]*)";
String part2 = Pattern.quote("/FileDownloader/4/outbound/31358/file+name.jpeg");
messageBody =  messageBody.replaceAll(part1 + part2, "cid: 14890411127853");
```

From the documentation for [Pattern.quote()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote(java.lang.String)):

> This method produces a String that can be used to create a Pattern that would match the string s as if it were a literal pattern.
>   Metacharacters or escape sequences in the input sequence will be given no special meaning.

Comment: @AbdulHameed Good catch, I got away with it because dot in regex also matches a single literal dot.

Comment: you have escaped the dot in the input instead of the pattern.. please edit

Comment: Thanx all, But I need to process file name for this and need to check if it contains any special character if yes then only add escape character. Is there any solution that works for both.

Comment: I don't understand your requirement.  You need to know in advance which pattern you are trying to match, and hence escaping metacharacters should not be a problem.  Please update your question _clearly_ and tell us what other problem you have.

Answer (score 2):

You just have to escape those characters using a backslash (`\`)

example:

```
String messageBody = "src=\"http://thinconnect.interactcrm.com:36061/FileDownloader/4/outbound/31358/file+name.jpeg\" style=\"height:225px\"";
messageBody =  messageBody.replaceAll("(http|https)://(?:[^\\s]*)/FileDownloader/4/outbound/31358/file\\+name\\.jpeg", "cid: 14890411127853");
```

similarly

```
String messageBody = "src=\"http://thinconnect.interactcrm.com:36061/FileDownloader/4/outbound/31358/file$name.jpeg\" style=\"height:225px\"";
messageBody =  messageBody.replaceAll("(http|https)://(?:[^\\s]*)/FileDownloader/4/outbound/31358/file\\$name\\.jpeg", "cid: 14890411127853");
```

Answer (score 0):

Did it this way.

```
    final String[] metaCharacters = {"^","$","{","}","[","]","(",")",".","+","-","&"};
    String filePath = "/4/outbound/31358/file+name.jpeg";
    for(String c: metaCharacters){
        if(filePath.contains(c)){
            filePath = filePath.replace(c, "\\"+c);
        }
    }
    String messageBody = "src=\"http://thinconnect.interactcrm.com:36061/FileDownloader/4/outbound/31358/file+name.jpeg\" style=\"height:225px\"";
    System.out.println(messageBody);
    messageBody =  messageBody.replaceAll("(http|https)://(?:[^\\s]*)/FileDownloader"+filePath, "cid: 14890411127853");
    System.out.println(messageBody);
```

Comment: No, this isn't the way to do this.  I understand your question now, see my updated answer for a better way to handle this.

Comment: @Tim Thank you. This is what I wanted.